# Create a 5 cent variance + - in bigdecimal comparison

Tags: java

We are calculating totals from percentages that must match up to the original total. However do to floating points, the the totals never match.

Example.

Total percentage is calculated from 327.81

Example of non rounded amounts

```
30%     98.343
20%     65.562
30%     98.343
20%     65.562
Total  327.81
```

Example of rounded amounts

```
30% 98.34
20% 65.56
30% 98.34
20% 65.56
Total 327.80
```

My amounts need to be rounded to a currency format, however you'll notice the rounded amount is 1 cent off 327.80 from being equal to our original amount of 327.81

In the end, I need to validate these two amounts are equal to each other - which obviously isn't going to validate. I've been told by management to add a .05 variance to my logic. I'm able to compare to values equal to each other, however I'm not certain how to add the variance into the equation. Could someone help me to figure out how to add this into my condition.

This is my current code comparing that they are equal to each other.

```
if (   this.pr.getRequisitionTotal() != null 
    && this.pr.getRequisitionTotal().compareTo(lineItemTotal) != 0
    && this.reviewedAuditActions()) 
{
    this.form.recordError("Requisition total must equal line item running total.");
}
```

Comment: Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: Rounded amounts generally do not add up to the original total - this is an unavoidable consequence of rounding. If your amounts must add up (why must they?) then you probably need to divide the total up into small discrete amounts (e.g. cents, or 10ths of cents) and allocate them in line with the percentages (which will often result in a small variance).

Comment: add or subtract the variance to the biggest amount. :)

Comment: Hi everyone, I am using bigdecimal, sorry I should of showed my data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution is to keep track of the accumulated deviation between the 'real' amounts and the rounded versions, and adjust rounding to keep the deviation less than 0.5.  Here's an implementation of the concept using BigDecimal, which makes it kind of wordy but avoids representation problems endemic if using floating point.

If you created a class named, for instance, `RoundingAccumulator` that encapsulates this behavior you could hide the messy details from the rest of your code.

```
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("327.81");
    BigDecimal[] percents = new BigDecimal[] {
            new BigDecimal(30),
            new BigDecimal(20),
            new BigDecimal(30),
            new BigDecimal(20) };
    BigDecimal accError = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal maxError = new BigDecimal("0.005");
    BigDecimal adjust   = new BigDecimal("0.01");
    BigDecimal hundred  = new BigDecimal("100");
    BigDecimal total    = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (BigDecimal pct : percents)
    {
        BigDecimal unrounded    = value.multiply(pct).divide(hundred); 
        BigDecimal rounded      = unrounded.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        BigDecimal error        = rounded.subtract(unrounded);
        BigDecimal correction   = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        accError = accError.add(error);
        if (accError.abs().compareTo(maxError) > 0)
            correction = accError.signum() > 0 ? adjust.negate() : adjust;
        rounded = rounded.add(correction);
        accError = accError.add(correction);
        System.out.println(unrounded.toString() + " " + rounded.toString() + " " + error.toString() + " " + accError.toString() + " " + correction.toString());

        total = total.add(rounded);
    }
    System.out.println("Total is " + total.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much better than what I planned on doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
final double EPSILON = 0.05;
double a = 0.5;
double b = 0.51;
if (Math.abs(a-b) <= EPSILON){
// match
}
else{
// no match
}
```